# Amazon web services working examples

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I have searched high and low to try and get the Product Advertising API to work - I have tried many examples from these forums and from the internet and it does not work. There has been some talk about modifying the WSDL and that does not work either.

Here is where I have been:
https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html
http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/3941
http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2609
http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/signing-amazon-product-advertising-api-cwcf-part-2/ *

*This was the best tutorial until AWS changed the WSDL with NO examples on how to deploy - I am actually starting to wonder if they even test their stuff before release!

Can anyone PLEASE point me to a working C# example?

**EDIT**
I am also aware of the information posted at 
 https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html 
 meaning that I am aware that the AssociateTag must now be included with every search etc.

Comment: Thank you Peter O for the revisions, I am so used to typing e-mails!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no documentataion.

I am forced to use other more-well documented technologies, such as the Google Books API.

When Amazon gets some documentation for a working system, I will untag this as the answer and tag the current one.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue recently, I used the last link mentioned above to create a c# application but since the new realease this stopped working and i couldn't fix it.

I downloaded this example:

http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/2481

And made some small changes and got it all working...

The main one changing the namespace to:

http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01

Throughout all the code......

I think I may have updated the code in a couple of other places and can help you if these errors occur

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for this. It is so disappointing. When you develop an API, I would expect people like amazon to have good documentation. There is something funny going on here. I want the right solution, and unfortunately hacking it does not sound correct. I downloaded the sample and there is a reference Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll not being present. Is there no working sample from Amazon?

Comment: Yeah I had to download the Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll and then reference it. I wouldn't say its hacking the solution as such just making it work with the latest release the change I've suggested above is just pointing it at the correct web service and its a simple date change. I couldn't find an up-to date Amazon working version so this could be your best bet as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this library [Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising)
You can use ISBN-10 or ISBN-13 to load book informations

**nuget**

```
PM> install-package Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising
```

**Example**

```
var authentication = new AmazonAuthentication();
authentication.AccessKey = "accesskey";
authentication.SecretKey = "secretkey";

var wrapper = new AmazonWrapper(authentication, AmazonEndpoint.US, "AssociateTag");
//Harry Potter and the Cursed Child
var result = wrapper.Lookup("978-1338099133");
```