# Amazon Marketplace WS Example / Pointers

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get a simple example with amazon MWS working. I downloaded the c# class library  from [here](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/feeds/v20090901/cSharp.html) and read through [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSDeveloperGuide._V148508213_.pdf) article but still can't seem to get a simple example working. I'm lost on the syntax as well as how to use the classes.

There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation out there as far as integrating their classes.

I have all my access keys and info I need to create the actual request, but I need help calling it using their classes.

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check through StackOverflow. There seems to be lots of people experiencing the same problem. I found this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510640/amazon-web-services-working-examples) that shows some working examples. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.. those links didn't help much but I did find something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499886/amazon-mws-problem-with-post-inventory-availability-data I'll ask for further help in the amazon support forums: http://www.amazonsellercommunity.com/forums/category.jspa?categoryID=4 Thanks.